# Error when starting Terminal (Failed to load code for plug-in com.apple.dt.IDESimulatorAvailability )

Tags: terminal, xcode

When I open the MacOS terminal I get the following error message and a prompt to install git. This happens EVERY TIME I try to run a command. I already have git installed but I tried clicking install anyway but the error + popup persist. I have also tried re-installing XCode. I think this started happening after the latest update. Any suggestions?

```
Tue Oct 11 14:47:32 on ttys001
2022-10-11 21:43:49.534 xcodebuild[25289:274311] [MT] DVTPlugInLoading: Failed to load code for plug-in com.apple.dt.IDESimulatorAvailability (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin), error = Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3588 "dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability, 0x0109): Symbol not found: (_OBJC_CLASS_$_SimDiskImage)
  Referenced from: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability'
  Expected in: '/Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator'" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle couldn’t be loaded., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability, NSDebugDescription=dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability, 0x0109): Symbol not found: (_OBJC_CLASS_$_SimDiskImage)
  Referenced from: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability'
  Expected in: '/Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator', NSBundlePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “IDESimulatorAvailability” couldn’t be loaded.}, dyldError = dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability, 0x0000): Symbol not found: (_OBJC_CLASS_$_SimDiskImage)
  Referenced from: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability'
  Expected in: '/Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator'
2022-10-11 21:43:49.597 xcodebuild[25289:274311] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /System/Volumes/Data/SWE/Apps/DT/BuildRoots/BuildRoot2/ActiveBuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-21304/DVTFoundation/PlugInArchitecture/DataModel/DVTPlugIn.m:374
Details:  Failed to load code for plug-in com.apple.dt.IDESimulatorAvailability (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin)
Please ensure Xcode packages are up-to-date — try running 'xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch'.

NSBundle error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3588 "dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability, 0x0109): Symbol not found: (_OBJC_CLASS_$_SimDiskImage)
  Referenced from: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability'
  Expected in: '/Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator'" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle couldn’t be loaded., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability, NSDebugDescription=dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability, 0x0109): Symbol not found: (_OBJC_CLASS_$_SimDiskImage)
  Referenced from: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability'
  Expected in: '/Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator', NSBundlePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “IDESimulatorAvailability” couldn’t be loaded.}
Object:   <DVTPlugIn: 0x600002f72da0>
Method:   -loadAssertingOnError:error:
Thread:   <_NSMainThread: 0x600000b38480>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints: 

Backtrace:
  0  0x000000010a9cdf61
  1  0x000000010a9cd495
  2  0x000000010a9cd6a1
  3  0x000000010a84439a
  4  0x000000010a7ffc52
  5  0x000000010a7fd9fe
  6  0x00007ff804f5a317
  7  0x00007ff804f677ee
  8  0x000000010aa1c581
  9  0x000000010a9f20b8
 10  0x000000010a7fd882
 11  0x000000010a7fdad4
 12  0x000000010b8e2f66
 13  0x000000010b8e2526
 14  0x000000010b8e1919
 15  0x000000010926a9a4
 16  0x0000000108e7620a
```

Mac Book pro 2018 13in, Intel

MacOS Monterey 12.6

BuildVersion:   21G115

Comment: What is in your shell startup files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think [this answer](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/3725#discussioncomment-3783261) can help you.

> Xcode is not fully installed. Run this to complete the install:
>
> ```
> xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
> ```

Comment: That was it thank you! This was the command for anybody else looking: `xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch`